# How can i check if a List is bigger then another List by 1?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
if (rise.Count > fall.Count)
            {
                rise.Remove(rise.Last());
            }
```

In this case im checking if the List rise is bigger then the List fall.
I want to check that only if the List rise is bigger then the List fall by 1 then do something.

For example if rise.Count is 418 and fall.Count is 417 then do something since rise is bigger then fall by one.
Or if rise.Count is 1123 and fall.Count is 1122 then do something.
All other cases don't do anything only if it's bigger by one.

How may i do it ?

Comment: How would you check if one integer was bigger than another integer by one?

Comment: Are you asking this.. `if(rise.Count - fall.Count == 1)`  ?

Comment: `if(rise.Count == fall.Count+1)`

Comment: Note that your removal code is 1) Slow and 2) Incorrect if the elements aren't unique. Use `rise.RemoveAt(rise.Count-1)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there

```
if ((rise.Count - fall.Count) == 1)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rise.Count - fall.Count == 1)           
    rise.Remove(rise.Last()); //your code here
```

Comment: Your checks are unnecessarily convoluted. For non negative integers `x` and `y`, `x - y == 1` implies `x > y`. (for `x==int.MinValue` and `y==int.MaxValue`, `x - y == 1` is true, but `x > y` false. Luckily that can never happen for `list.Count`)

Comment: Is it now ok? as a trainee, I am habituated to use so :)

Comment: You don't need the checks if rise is bigger then fall. If not, the substraction will return a (negativ) number != 1.